# how to pass data from checkbox to another activity

Tags: java, android

```
private void buildEmailText() {
    if (box1.isChecked()) emailText += "\nCoca-Cola";
    if (box2.isChecked()) emailText += "\nFanta";
    if (box3.isChecked()) emailText += "\nInca Cola";
```

this from one activity

```
  if (box4.isChecked()) emailText += "\nEl Boricua Original";
  if (box5.isChecked()) emailText += "\nEl Boricua de Pollo";
```

**this from another activity**

```
 if (box6.isChecked()) emailText += "\nBebida 1/2 litro";
 if (box7.isChecked()) emailText += "\nBebida 1 1/2 litro";
```

and i need that one option from this selected in diferent activities will be included in one mail

as a sample i need that will be in mail is

```
El boricua original
Bebida 1/2 litro
fanta
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need start activity for result, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), whichDrink.class);
intent.putExtra("Bebida 1/2 litro","Bebida 1/2 litro");
intent.putExtra("Bebida 1 1/2 litro","Bebida 1 1/2 litro");
startActivityForResult (intent, 0);
```

and then in whichDrink activity class:

```
String firstValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bebida 1/2 litro");
String secondValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bebida 1 1/2 litro");
```

and at least you should extract these key strings to constants

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), whichDrink.class.class);
intent.putExtra("DATA1","Bebida 1/2 litro");
intent.putExtra("DATA2","Bebida 1 1/2 litro");
startActivity(intent);
```

Receive data in `whichDrink.class`like this

```
String DATA1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("DATA1");
String DATA2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("DATA2");
```

Comment: how it can helps to put data in email from other activities?

Comment: you can use sharedprefrence.

Comment: @alisa use **`SharedPreferences`**

Comment: private void buildEmailText() {
        if (box1.isChecked()) emailText += "\nCoca-Cola";
        if (box2.isChecked()) emailText += "\nFanta";
        if (box3.isChecked()) emailText += "\nInca Cola";

    }
    private void buildEmailText1(){
        if (box4.isChecked()) emailText += "\nEl Boricua Original";
        if (box5.isChecked()) emailText += "\nEl Boricua de Pollo";
    }

    private void buildEmailText2(){
        if (box6.isChecked()) emailText += "\nBebida 1/2 litro";
        if (box7.isChecked()) emailText += "\nBebida 1 1/2 litro";
    }

Comment: but app crashes when press send button

Comment: please send the logcat.

Comment: you send data in Email or Message.

Comment: when press button to send email